# Trying to install Angular/cli 17 but it installs version 11.1.2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to install Angular/cli 17 but it installs version 11.1.2.
I have tried to do a clean install and nothing, I have uninstalled several times angular/cli but it keeps installing version 11.1.2.
The Node version is lts 20.11.0.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NIIW.png)
I need the angular/cli@17.0.3

I have tried everything but there is no way to get version 17 installed.

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: This is more of a Superuser than Stackover question i think. If you want to improve the chances of getting an answer, edit your question and add details of specifically what commands you have run as well as the output. Your screenshot is an image which is not great per @toyotas comment, but without the commands your executing its very difficult to help you too. If i had to guess, it sounds like you might have installed v11 globally at some point?

Answer (score 2):

What command do you run?

`npm i -g angular/cli@17.0.3`

OR

`npm i angular/cli@17.0.3` in the repo folder?

check your the repo version runnning `npm list` and global one `npm list -g`